# How to take persistable uri permission with PickVisualMedia()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

In my app I use images from phone galery. I recive uri and write it to database.
When I want to use this uri I get error, for example:
`java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid ( 10192 ) does not have permission to access picker uri: content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000033`

On start my app I send request for permissions:

```
  val permissionState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA

        )
    )

    SideEffect() {
        permissionState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
    }
```

But I get error when:

```
 fun getImgBitmap(img: String, context: Context): Bitmap {
            val source: ImageDecoder.Source
            val bitmap: Bitmap

            source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, Uri.parse(img))
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
 .....

}
```

[image]

**The problem appears on API > 29**

For API > 29 I use:

```
 val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
          
   contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(Uri.parse(img), takeFlags)


  source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, Uri.parse(img))
  bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
```

(img is String)

And get: `java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10195 and Uri content://media/...`

Comment: You do not need that READ permission.

Comment: You did not tell how you obtained your uri.

Comment: If you directly use the uri.. before putting in database .. what happens?

Comment: I can use uri.      val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()
    ) {
        ///update with uri
    }     But after restart app get this error.

Answer (score 1):

when I get uri write next line:

```
  val name = context.packageName
   context.grantUriPermission(name, it, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

---

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()
    ) {it ->
                 **val name = context.packageName
                context.grantUriPermission(name, it, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)**
        //savetodatabase 
    }
```

seems to work...

Comment: Nice you found a solution. But it does not work for me. Nor did the takePersistableUriPermission().

Comment: The subject of your post should have been:  How to take persistable uri permission with PickVisualMedia() ? As all is about storing an uri for later use.

Comment: changed  subject )

Comment: Had a typo. takePersistableUriPermission() is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Take persistable uri permission if you want to use an uri later or in a different activity.

Comment: I updated topic

Comment: `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(Uri.parse(img)` img? Please post complete code of contract. We dont know what you do.

Comment: looks like I found the answer. perhaps you meant this.  postes answer